# Increase textual counter after html file type image upload

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form where I check the character limit a user can put in a textfield and the 'onkeyup' attribute updates this in realtime 
[image: Example of how it looks like]

Now I want to do the same thing for image uploading where as soon as a user selects an Image from his computer that I want to update the counter (note: select not yet send the form).
image showing what i want to do:
[image: Default look]

As can be seen in this picture, I want the 0/10 to become 1/10 here since an image (to be uploaded later) has been selected:
[image]

If someone is kind enough to help me, I would like to use this occasion to ask a side question regarding the same issue:
The code I use looks as follows:

```
<tr>
   <td></td>
   <td><input id="pictureInputBox" type="file"  name="pictureInputBox"/></td>
   <td class="formhelp"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><a href="#" id="AddMorePicturesBox" onclick="checkPictureCount();">Add More Pictures</a></td>
    <td class="formhelp"></td>
</tr>
```

How can I make another "pictureInputBox" appear when clicking on the link with setting a maximum of 10 of these to appear (one at a time)?

Kind regards,
Dennis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the following answers both of your questions:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" value="add more files" id="add-files" />
<span id="selected-files-counter">0</span>/10 Pictures
<ul id="files-list">
    <li><input type="file" name="photos[]" /></li>
</ul>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var selectedFilesCounter = 0;
    var fileElementsCounter = 1;
    var filesListEl = $('#files-list');
    var selectedFilesEl = $('#selected-files-counter');

    $('#add-files').click(function(){
        if(fileElementsCounter < 10) {
            filesListEl.append('<li><input type="file" name="photos[]" /></li>');
            fileElementsCounter++;
        }
    });

    $(document).on( 'change', 'input[type=file]', function(e) {
        if($(this).val() === '') {
            selectedFilesCounter--;
        } else {
            selectedFilesCounter++;
        }
        selectedFilesEl.html(selectedFilesCounter);
    });
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/j3E7A/

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do it. Instead of using a function with `onclick`, I use jQuery's `.on()` to bind to the `AddMorePicturesBox` link click or when `pictureInputBox` value changes. You would need to add `class="pictureInputBox"` to your existing `input="file"`.

```
$(function(){
    $('#AddMorePicturesBox').on('click', function(){
        if($('.pictureInputBox').length < 10){
            $(this).parent().parent().before('<tr><td></td><td><input type="file" name="pictureInputBox" class="pictureInputBox" /></td><td class="formhelp"></td></tr>');
        }
        else{
            alert('You can only have 10 files');
        }
    });
    $(document).on('change', '.pictureInputBox', function(){
        var fileCount = 0;
        $('.pictureInputBox').each(function(index,value){
            if($(this).val() != ''){
                fileCount++;
                $(this).parent()
                .next('.formhelp').html(fileCount+'/10 pictures');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You can see an example at - http://jsfiddle.net/8k3N3/

Comment: Thank you, this helped me also even though I accepted the answer above!